# Confusion about Dir[] and File.join() in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, dir

I meet a simple program about `Dir[]` and `File.join()` in Ruby,

```
blobs_dir = '/path/to/dir'
Dir[File.join(blobs_dir, "**", "*")].each do |file|
       FileUtils.rm_rf(file) if File.symlink?(file)
```

I have two confusions:

Firstly, what do the second and third parameters mean in `File.join(@blobs_dir, "**", "*")`?

Secondly, what's the usage the `Dir[]` in Ruby? I only know it's Equivalent to `Dir.glob()`, however, I am not clear with `Dir.glob()` indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File.join() simply concats all its arguments with separate slash. 
For instance,

```
File.join("a", "b", "c")
```

returns "a/b/c". It is alsmost equivalent to more frequently used Array's join method, just like this:

```
["hello", "ruby", "world"].join(", ")
# => "hello, ruby, world"
```

Using File.join(), however, additionaly does two things: it clarifies that you are getting something related to file paths, and adds '/' as argument (instead of ", " in my Array example). Since Ruby is all about aliases that better describe your intentions, this method better suits the task.

Dir[] method accepts string or array of such strings as a simple search pattern, with "*" as all files or directories, and "**" as directories within other directories. For instance,

```
Dir["/var/*"]
# => ["/var/lock", "/var/backups", "/var/lib", "/var/tmp", "/var/opt", "/var/local", "/var/run", "/var/spool", "/var/log", "/var/cache", "/var/mail"]
```

and

```
Dir["/var/**/*"]
# => ["/var/lock", "/var/backups", "/var/backups/dpkg.status.3.gz", "/var/backups/passwd.bak" ... (all files in all dirs in '/var')]
```

It is a common and very convinient way to list or traverse directories recursively

Answer (score 6):

```
File.join(blobs_dir, "**", "*")
```

This just build the path pattern for the glob. The result is `/path/to/dir/**/*`

`**` and `*`'s meaning:

`*`: Matches any file
`**`: Matches directories recursively

So your code is used to delete every symlink inside the directory `/path/to/dir`.

Comment: You almost completed your answer.. Just mention `Dir::[]` works same as `Dir::glob`.

Comment: Hum.. I see. Actually I was looking for the line *however, I am not clear with Dir.glob() indeed.* You got my +1. :-)

Answer (score 5):

[`File::join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-join) is used to join path components with separator `File::SEPARATOR` (normally `/`):

```
File.join('a', 'b', 'c')
# => "a/b/c"
```

[`Dir::glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) returns filenames  that matched with the pattern.

The given pattern `/path/to/dir/**/*` match any file recursively (below `/path/to/dir`).

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

```
glob -- Expands pattern, which is an Array of patterns or a pattern String, and returns the results as matches or as arguments given to the block.
*    -- Matches any file
**   -- Matches directories recursively
```